# Meteor Deploy Error

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, meteor, meteor-up

Hi there I am trying to deploy my meteor app, I am using meteor up. Meteor setup works fine. I have update node and npm on both my local and server machines. ruining node version node 4.6.0 and npm 3.10.9 and the latest version on meteor. But i keep getting this log error.

```
[40.69.194.127] => Starting meteor app on port:80                                          
[40.69.194.127]     at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)            
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                    
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                      
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                            
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)                                                   
    at require (module.js:380:17)                                                          
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)                    
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                  
npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,              
npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm                    
npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the             
npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:                       
npm WARN deprecated                                                                        
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2                                          
npm WARN deprecated                                                                        
npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:                          
npm WARN deprecated                                                                        
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest                                            
npm WARN deprecated                                                                        
npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you            
npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if           
npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)                    
npm WARN deprecated                                                                        
npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with                      
npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS           
npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small          
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and            
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.                                                       
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description                               
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.                         
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data                               
npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/pr

assert.js:93                                                                               
  throw new assert.AssertionError({                                                        
        ^                                                                                  
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"                                                 
    at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)               
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)            
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                    
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                      
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                            
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)                                                   
    at require (module.js:380:17)                                                          
    at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)                    
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

My server is on azure and it is a Ubuntu 14 machine.
Can some on please help me on this i have stuck on this a long time now.

Thanks

Comment: what is at `/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108` ?

Comment: I cannot seem to find this path . I canot find the bundle folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you'll need to change `mup.js` settings to use the docker image as below:

```
{
  meteor: {
    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    // ...
  },
}
```

[image]

For more details, you can check the answers of @abernix inside this link: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7475.